# Azure B2C - Custom policies - Replacing Let's Encrypt certificate for a Comodo/Sectigo certificate not allowed

Tags: azure, entra-id

I have an Azure B2C tenant which uses custom policies to connect to our own API.
The policy is currently provisioned with a *.something.dev certificate and expires every 3 months.
The plan is to replace this current certificate with a CA issued certificate so we don't have to replace the certificate 4 times a year, but only once.

The error we receive after uploading a Comodo CA certificate however is
`Microsoft.Cpim.Common.PolicyException`.

Is there any place we could have set a CA or limitations in Azure so this will cause these issues? I do not recall making any CA related settings in Azure.

If we replace the Comodo CA with a Let's Encrypt certificate the service works again.
The code on our side is allowing the thumbprint of both certificates, so that's not causing the issue.

I've tried so far:

- Replacing our URL on the webservice (moved from something.test.dev to someotherdomain.com).
- Replaced 2048 certificates with 4096 and visa versa.
- Created new policies (B2C_1A_EnrichmentApiClientCertificate)
- Created a new b2c tenant and doing all settings all over again.
- If I set our own API offline I get this error: `Microsoft.Cpim.Common.Web.ConnectionException` so I'm 100% sure we're calling this exact API.
- Removed any CAA record, to see if that has any relation to it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to this question lies in the certificate-chain.

The chain was misconfigured and we had non-root certificates placed in the root store on the server which was causing issues.

Removing the wrong certificates fixed this issue for us.

How did we solve this:

- Compared a working computer/server mmc.exe with a non-working environment and remove the certificates which aren't matching.